# How to redirect a non-existing directory to a sub-domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

During the last 2 hours I'm trying to achieve the following with no success.

I have a domain (lets call it www.test.com) which is assigned to a specific folder in my host, for example : public_html/test.

Now, what I'm trying to do is, I want to redirect a specific url (www.test.com/move) to a subdomain that exists and is assigned to another folder inside the public_html.

I want this to happen only for the specific directory (move) which does not exist inside the test folder.

I guesss this can be done through .htaccesss but I fail miserably every time.

Any ideas on what I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple if you only want to do that specific URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^move$ http://subdomain.test.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Very nice and simple. thank you. The problem is that the result isnt what I expected it to be. Anyway, the next step belongs to another question probably if I cant find out how to do it.

Comment: @NickDF If you were looking to redirect an entire directory or pass query strings I can update the answer to include.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for not replying earlier. Although I've solved the problem, I would be very interested on how to pass query strings as well. This might be useful for future reference.

Comment: @NickDf you can use the [QSA] flag at the end of the rule to perform a query string append.